# Why IConfiguration section mixes ienumerable values?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to use different appsettings.json files based on ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable. My configuration files looks like this:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "Bar": [
      "production1",
      "production2",
      "production3",
      "production4"
    ]
  }
}
```

**appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "Bar": [
      "development1"
    ]
  }
}
```

In startup class constructor I'm binding IConfigurationSection to object Json representation, and array values are mixed from two appsettins...

[image]

Is this by design? How can I handle diffrent array value for each configuration?

Comment: `appsettings.json` is intended for settings that don't change based on environment, it is applied to every environment (by default). Your production specific settings should go in `appsettings.Production.json`.

Comment: `Is this by design?` **Yes**, `How can I handle diffrent array value for each configuration?` The previous comment does a good job of explaining how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is unfortunately somewhat by design. The reason for this is the way configuration works under the hood. While you are usually writing configuration in a nested JSON structure, the parsed configuration is actually a flat key/value structure.

In your case, the configuration from your `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
"Foo:Bar:0": "production1"
"Foo:Bar:1": "production2"
"Foo:Bar:2": "production3"
"Foo:Bar:3": "production4"
```

Similarly, the configuration from your `appsettings.Development.json` looks like this:

```
"Foo:Bar:0": "development1"
```

You might already see how this becomes a problem when both files apply: Because multiple configuration sources are merged, later sources will overwrite values from earlier sources. So the `Foo:Bar:0` key from the `appsettings.json` is overwritten by `appsettings.Development.json`. But the other three items stay. So the final result looks like this:

```
"Foo:Bar:0": "development1"
"Foo:Bar:1": "production2"
"Foo:Bar:2": "production3"
"Foo:Bar:3": "production4"
```

And that's how you end up with what you have.

There isn't really a way around this. My recommendation would be to avoid specifying defaults in your `appsettings.json` which you will have to overwrite in the environment-specific configuration. Instead, create a `appsettings.Production.json` in which you specify the production-specific values.